# Xamarin App with Authentication, Authorization and persistance layer using Azure Services

Tags: azure, authentication, xamarin.forms, authorization, azure-cosmosdb

I have no experience in Cloud Based services and therefore i don't know what benefits Azure has that i can use.

My plan is to make a Xamarin.Forms app where is the functionality to login a user with specific roles to authorize several actions in the app.

Furthermore, the app should have a **persistance layer** to load the data thats already existing. I found **Azure CosmosDB** as a good service for that.

What Azure Service i can use for Authentication and Authorization? How can i combine these two Services togehter?

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: hi,does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to implement the secure access for cosmos db data.I have 2 scenarios for your reference:

1.**Use resource token to control the access for cosmos db**:As we know, we could use the master key for the account, you can create user resources and permission resources per database. A resource token is associated with a permission in a database and determines whether the user has access (read-write, read-only, or no access) to an application resource in the database. Application resources include container, documents, attachments, stored procedures, triggers, and UDFs. The resource token is then used during authentication to provide or deny access to the resource.

You could get more details from this link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/secure-access-to-data

2.Use Access control (IAM):

[image]

IAM provides role-based access control and integrates with Active Directory. You can use built in roles or custom roles for individuals and groups.Namely, You can integrate all your APP users into AD, group them and give permission to each group.More details,please refer to this link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/role-based-access-control

Comment: Hi, i am sorry for answering so late. because this is a private project, i had not much time to check if this is what i need. I checked your answer now and think the second approach is the right one for my App.
But i am still not sure how i can create a user and ensure the user logs in with his account saved in the AD. guess i have to read more about it. if there are other tipps you can give me, it will be much appreciated!